# DB manager not updating

Tags: qgis, spatialite

I'm trying to learn how to use spatialite databases, so have made a few experimental ones. When I delete them, however, they still show up in QGIS's DB Manager. If I try to open them it comes up with a 'database does not exist' type error, but it will not let me delete them, or update itself. Worse still, I created a new spatialite layer in QGIS and named it the same as an old one (but in a different file location). Now DB manager just shows me the old one.

How can I get DB manager to update itself?

I've tried the obvious refresh button, but to no effect.

Comment: Can you add which version of QGIS you are using please? This could help potential answerers know if it's due to a bug for a specific QGIS version.

Comment: And have you also tried just restarting QGIS to see if DB manager updates itself?

Comment: Probably best to use the QGIS Browser to "delete" spatialite databases that no longer exist. Also, make sure database names are unique.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using version 2.4.0. Yes, I have tried restarting QGIS but they are still there. With regards deleting and the answer to this question, yes deleting the database connections from QGIS browser worked, thanks. As a feature suggestion, though, it would be more intuitive if all the elements recognized what existed and what did not, if there is some way to make that work.